# Let $f(\frac ab)=ab$, where $\frac ab$ is irreducible, in $\mathbb Q^+$. What is $\sum_{x\in\mathbb Q^+}\frac 1{f(x)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation, rational-numbers

> Let $f(\frac ab)=ab$, where $\frac ab$ is irreducible, in $\mathbb Q^+$. What is $\sum_{x\in\mathbb Q^+}\frac 1{f(x)^2}$?

Club challenge problem. I don't think it's possible to do with only high school calculus. Help, please?

Comment: Oddly enough, there is a vote to close as “not a real question”. Perhaps it was a mistake. I hope so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note first that $f$ is multiplicative over the rationals in some sense.  More precisely, if $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ are in reduced form and $(a,d) = (b,c) = 1$, we have that $f(\frac{ac}{bd}) = f(\frac{a}{b}) \cdot f(\frac{c}{d})$.

You have to justify this next step, but (if the sum behaves nicely) we can thus split it up into an infinite product using unique factorization of the rationals:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x \in \mathbb{Q}^+} \frac{1}{f(x)^2} &=
\prod_{p \text{ prime}} \left(\cdots + \frac{1}{f(p^{-2})^2} + \frac{1}{f(p^{-1})^2} + \frac{1}{f(1)^2} + \frac{1}{f(p^1)^2} + \frac{1}{f(p^2)^2} + \cdots\right)
\\
&= \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \left( 1 + \frac{2}{p^2} + \frac{2}{p^4} + \frac{2}{p^6} + \cdots \right)
\\
&= \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \left( \frac{2}{1 - \frac{1}{p^2}} - 1 \right)
= \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \left( \frac{p^2 + 1}{p^2 - 1} \right)
\end{align*}
$$
I admit I am unsure of how to evaluate this product, but this seems helpful.

**Update:** This product evaluates to $\frac52$!  See the comments for an explanation.

Comment: Hmm. $\prod_{p \text{ prime}}(1-p^{-2})^{-1}=\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$, but what is $\prod_{p \text{ prime}}(1+p^{-2})$? I have no idea. Well, it is $\sum_n n^{-2}$ taken over all square free numbers. Does that help?

Comment: Every natural number $k$ is uniquely factorizable as $k=m^2n$ with $n$ squarefree. Substitute that into the known sum $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}k^{-2}$ to get $\pi^2/6=\zeta(4)\sum_n n^{-2}$ with the latter sum taken over the square free numbers. (I admit to not being sober at the moment, so this may be wrong. But if not, it seems to solve the problem.)

Comment: Ah, a simpler way than mine leads to the same Euler product more directly! However, does anybody have an idea why (or why not) the result seems to be $\frac 52$? -- Oh, I just see that @HaraldHanche-Olsen is sober enough as his idea leads to $\frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)}=\frac52$. Cheers!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It must be the power of red wine. But the simplicity of the answer hints that there should be a more direct derivation, or shall we say less transcendent?

Comment: @HaraldHancheOlsen:  [Yes!](https://xkcd.com/323/)  (Not as to whether some other argument is simpler, but rather an affirmation of the other, no less important part of your comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts, too long to fit a comment.

Let $c(n)$ denote the number of divisors $d|n$ such that gcd$(d,\frac{n}{d})=1$.

It is easy to show that $f(x)= \pm n$ has exactly $2c(n)$ solutions.

Then, after rearranging (we can since the series is positive), the sum becomes

$$ \sum_n \frac{2c(n)}{n^2} \,.$$

Now I claim that $c(n)=2^{f(n)}$ where $f(n)$ is the number of prime divisors of $n$. This can be proven easily by either observing that if $p|n$ then $p$ either divides $d$ OR $\frac{n}{d}$ but not both, or by observing that $c(n)$ is a multiplicative function.

Thus the problem asks to calculate

$$2\sum_n \frac{2^{f(n)}}{n^2} \,.$$

Here is where I have no idea on how to proceed further.

One idea would be to transform the series into an Euler product over the primes. Another would be to try to use the multiplicative of $c$, since this looks like the ideas behind Dirichclet L-series might help (I have absolutely no idea about that though).